# Excel services snapshot removes page breaks

Tags: excel, sharepoint, service

I am using Sharepoint Excel services to produce reports, and noticed that when users download their excel services workbooks as a snapshot, any page breaks set up in the original spreadsheet are lost.  I cant seem to find any mention of this problem in any sharepoint forums or microsoft, just wondering if anyone else has experienced this or even has a solution?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A lot of information and functions of the workbook are not available in Excel Services. 
Also the Snapshot does not "remember" such settings like page break or in my case landscape orientation for printing.

Here are some references for what is supported and what is not supported:
Snapshot:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Open-a-workbook-or-snapshot-in-Excel-from-Excel-Services-0d7c0465-6ea9-4a1e-993b-54bd1099d604
Difference Excel / Services
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Differences-between-using-a-workbook-in-Excel-and-Excel-Services-b690ef8c-a26a-4673-b426-1852f8d77fd0